# There is a hidden decimal point in values of one column in my Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table for which I have imported data from an Excel spreadsheet using ETL in SSMS by TASK>IMPORT DATA

At that time I didn't check the format of number values in Excel I guess and now in my table only some values have hidden decimal points which is showing up in my SSRS report in the drop down which displays that column values

The values are shown when I run the query are like below

```
Select * 
From tbl_name 
Where column_name Like '%.%'
```

Please if anyone can help in removing the decimal in my column values that would be great

I tried to run the below query and it threw and error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, NEW_CNTRY_RGN_CODE) 
FROM table_Name 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%.%'
```

I get an error:

> Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
> Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 9600900900.000000

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a decimal value to an int? Of course you get an error. Convert it to a decimal instead. `convert(bigint, convert(decimal(16,0),'9600900900.000001'))`

Comment: what is the data type for column `NEW_CNTRY_RGN_CODE` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `BIGINT` instead of `INT`

> max value for int is 2,147,483,647
> int   -   2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

[int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, NEW_CNTRY_RGN_CODE) 
FROM table_Name 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: That is part of the problem, but won't work unless you convert to a decimal first (or use a sub_string to remove the decimal point.

Comment: just run this
`SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, 123131231231.123)`
you will see it returns 123131231231

Comment: Have you tried OP's sample data? `select convert(bigint, '9600900900.000000')`

Comment: `select convert(bigint, '9600900900.000000')` gives convert error...
it means NEW_CNTRY_RGN_CODE is not char but a numeric data...

Comment: varchar seems the most likely way the data is being stored... but needs OP to clarify.